# Hidden form submit is not working in Ios

Tags: javascript, form-submit

Hi I am developing a application using javascript, html, css. it will run as a application and web application. I am creating a hidden form submit like below.

```
hiddenFormSubmit:function(path, params, method) {    
    var form;
    form = document.forms.namedItem('myForm');
    if(form === null){
        method = method || 'post'; 
        form = document.createElement('form');
        form.setAttribute('name', 'servicesForm');
        form.setAttribute('method', method);
        form.setAttribute('action', path);
        form.setAttribute('target', 'report');
        document.body.appendChild(form);
    }
    else{
        form.innerHTML = '';
    }
    for(var key in params) {
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
            hiddenField.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
            hiddenField.setAttribute('name', params[key].id);
            hiddenField.setAttribute('value', params[key].value);
            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
         }
    }


        window.open('','report');

    form.submit();
    },
```

This one is working perfectly in desktop browsers and mobile browsers. But not working from iOs app.In desktop browsers and mobile browsers it is opening a new window as expected. But in iOs app it is opening a new window with some errors. Do I need to add anything to make work in iOs app. Please suggest.

Comment: What errors does this open the window with?

Comment: it is opening a new window with the same url we are in. not with the form submission url. I want to know whether we need to add any extra attribute to make it work with iOs.